# ComboBoxTableCell does not show ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have this model:

```
public class AbstractMappingRow {

private StringProperty abstractService = new SimpleStringProperty();
private StringProperty taskId = new SimpleStringProperty();
private StringProperty taskName = new SimpleStringProperty();

public AbstractMappingRow(String taksNameString, String taskIdString, String abstractServiceString) {
    super();

    this.abstractService = new SimpleStringProperty(abstractServiceString);
    this.taskId = new SimpleStringProperty(taskIdString);
    this.taskName = new SimpleStringProperty(taksNameString);
}
public StringProperty getAbstractService() {
    return abstractService;
}
public void setAbstractService(StringProperty abstractService) {
    this.abstractService = abstractService;
}
public StringProperty getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}
public void setTaskId(StringProperty taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}
public StringProperty getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}
public void setTaskName(StringProperty taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

}
```

I am trying to have a table row [ String - String - ComboBox with Strings ]. So I set up the table like this:

```
    TableColumn<AbstractMappingRow,String> taskIdCol = new TableColumn<>("Task ID");      
    taskIdCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<AbstractMappingRow, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<AbstractMappingRow, String> p) {
            return p.getValue().getTaskId();
        }
     });

    mappingTable.getColumns().add(taskIdCol);

    TableColumn<AbstractMappingRow,String> taskNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Task Name");
    taskNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<AbstractMappingRow, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<AbstractMappingRow, String> p) {
            return p.getValue().getTaskName();
        }
     });

    mappingTable.getColumns().add(taskNameCol);

    TableColumn<AbstractMappingRow, String> abstractServiceCol = new TableColumn<>("Abstrakter Dienst");
    abstractServiceCol.setMinWidth( 200 );
    abstractServiceCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getAbstractService());
    abstractServiceCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<AbstractMappingRow, String>forTableColumn(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "3"))); 

    mappingTable.getColumns().add(abstractServiceCol);

    mappingTable.getItems().add(new AbstractMappingRow("test", "test", "3"));
```

But as a result, I do not see any ComboBox in the third column which is supposed to contain the values "1" and "3". Instead, I see this:

[image]

What am I missing to make the ComboBox show up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake: I forgot to set

```
mappingTable.setEditable(true);
```

Thanks!